# Adafruit ServoHat Second Row of Ground Pins

Tags: adafruit

I am trying to access the second row of ground pins on the Adafruit ServoHat, however, these pins don't seem to work. Here is the link to the schematic diagram of the servo hat: https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/adafruit-16-channel-pwm-servo-hat-for-raspberry-pi.pdf

On page 27 of 28, the GND pins on the second row on the right of the top diagram are the ones I am referring to. It seems like the top row is connected, but all rows below it aren't. Is there a way I can use the other GND rows?

Comment: Are you sure those other rows are ground pins?  I assumed they were just a patch area for you to fit your own components.

Comment: @joan Ahh, I just assumed they were ground pins. It seems like it is just a patch area then, thanks :)